# Two Docker images in GitLab CI .yaml

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to extend one of my CI jobs on GitLab:

```
deploy-stage:
  image: python:3.5
  environment: stage
  script:
  - pip install awscli
  - aws s3 cp dist s3://$S3_BUCKET_STAGE/ --recursive
  only:
    - stage
```

What I want to achieve is to be able to build code from Vue.js files (by using `npm run build`), but to do this I need Node.js. But I also need Python to be able to upload files to S3. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After some help from here I ended up with such `gitlab-ci.yml` configuration:

```
build-stage:
  stage: build
  image: node:latest
  environment:
    name: stage
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run build-stage
  only:
    - stage
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 2 hrs
    paths:
      - dist/

deploy-stage:
  stage: deploy
  image: python:3.5
  environment:
    name: stage
  script:
    - pip install awscli
    - aws s3 cp dist s3://$S3_BUCKET_STAGE/ --recursive
  dependencies:
    - build-stage
  only:
    - stage
```

It's easy and readable. No need for any custom images from Docker - just do one job and then move results to the next job. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

You could just use 2 separates build steps and use artifacts to pass the build between the steps.

What you could do is in your first build step you use an image with `vue.js` and run `npm run build` and any other steps you need to do.

At the end of job you specify [artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pipelines/job_artifacts.html).

```
artifacts:
  paths:
    - build
```

This would pass the folder build to the next job.

Then you can run your second job using python to upload the contents to S3.

This gives you the freedom to build your program in the way you want without having to limit yourself to a specific environment.

If you can't find an image that does what you need you can either create your own or, if build time isn't important, you can use a base image and install everything you need as part of your job.

```
image: node:alpine
  before_script:
    - yum install curl -y && yum update -y
  script:
    - npm run build
```

The above snippet would install curl on a node alpine image.

Comment: Yes, that seems easier to do. I will dive into it - I recently read that I also have to set `expire` for artifcats so they don't stay there forever :P I think I will build image for node then `npm run build` then move to second job with python and aws

Comment: Ah yes. If it's a steady flowing project I tend to keep artifacts for 1 week. If no issues has occurred by then it's fine. Worst case you can always just re-run the pipeline from the commit to recreate the artifact should you need it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest following approaches:

First, simple. Use general-purpose container as a base image, lets say `ubuntu` and install both `python` and `npm` there.

Why not use `python` image and install there `npm` or vice versa:

- your package manager (`apt`/`apk`) becomes implicit unless you specify `python:3-alpine` or whatever. I personally prefer explicit definition because you teammates would be confused with question "What is the manager for npm image?" if they are not familiar with it.
- the set of preinstalled packages is also undefined and can change from version to version. Does `bash` exist in `python:3`?
- changing the version of one tool (let's say `python2 -> python3`) could dramatically influence the image if it is used as a base one for all others.
- tomorrow you will need to add 3rd tool (`gcc`?) to your image.

So having a general purpose base image with all needed tools installed explicitly looks for me as a best idea.

Also to note, you would probably need to separate your image building process from using this image. I prefer having first `prepare` stage in my `gitlab` CI which build all necessary images and puts them into provided by GitLab private docker registry.

Comment: That's interesting. Can I build this general purpose base image using only GitLab CI or I will have to prepare one locally first and then upload it to private Docker registry? I'm a beginner when it comes to Docker

Comment: Of course you can build it with gitlab. Use `docker:dind` service and `docker:latest` as a builder

Comment: You need to connect `docker:dind` as a shared service and create new job (on `prepare` stage), based on `docker:latest` or `docker:stable` (e.g.) image. In your job you could call `docker` CLI while service will provide daemon

Comment: What should I read to fully understand those things? I don't fully grasp the idea yet and I want to :)

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-docker-images-and-host-a-docker-image-repository-with-gitlab

https://medium.com/@tonywooster/docker-in-docker-in-gitlab-runners-220caeb708ca

Comment: Another question: can I build in one job and push to AWS in other? And then create separate pipelines for `staging` and `production` deployments?

Comment: When you build image, you get artifact (image file) - you have to push it to some registry. on another stage you may push it to AWS from registry, but frankly speaking I've never worked with AWS and not an expert here